# How can I merge hash-maps that are inside a collection of vectors in clojure?

Tags: clojure

Given collection of vectors of separated hash-maps

How can I go from :

```
[[{:a 1} {:b 2} {:c 3}] [{:a 4} {:b 5} {:c 6}] [{:a 7} {:b 8} {:c 9}]]
```

To:

```
[[{:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}] [{:a 4 :b 5 :c 6}] [{:a 7 :b 8 :c 9}]]
```

Thanks you for your answers!

Comment: The answers as given return the requested nested structure to the data - a vector of vectors, each inner vector containing a single map. It is hard to envisage why this structure is necessary when it would seem simpler to work with a a sequence of maps as would be returned by `(map (partial apply merge) input-coll)`. What aspect of the downstream function or API requires the vector of unitary vectors of maps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(def coll [[{:a 1} {:b 2} {:c 3}] [{:a 4} {:b 5} {:c 6}] [{:a 7} {:b 8} {:c 9}]])

(mapv (fn [v] [(apply merge v)]) coll)
;; => [[{:a 1 :c 3 :b 2}] [{:a 4 :c 6 :b 5}] [{:a 7 :c 9 :b 8}]]
```

Comment: `mapv` (delivers a vector instead of a lazy sequence) is Clojure >= 4. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 4):

```
(def data [[{:a 1} {:b 2} {:c 3}] [{:a 4} {:b 5} {:c 6}] [{:a 7} {:b 8} {:c 9}]])

(mapv #(-> [(into {} %)]) data)
```

Comment: I've not seen the `#(-> ...)` idiom before. Is it a work-around for the behavior of the shorthand `#()` syntax when a data literal like `[]` is used?

Comment: Yup, it is. I have never seen this yet in any clojure code, except for mine :)

Comment: what's the advantage over ``#(vector (into {} %))`` ?

Comment: Nothing as such, just that in this case we use vector literal notation